# iOS App crash while contact syncing in background from google contacts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, abaddressbook, google-contacts-api

I am accessing native contacts in my app and sending it to my server.

Now Problem occurs when i started syncing contact from google contacts(10k contacts) on my ios device and start my app (first time after installing) than app crashes. But if my app is opened/used before after installing than not crashed.

What is the cause? Can anyone help me?

Steps:

1. Install my app from App store but i am not opening it.
2. Start Google contacts sync from settings.
3. Opening my app and it crashes.

Comment: Can you post the crash log? Error message?

Comment: Since it in my device. So i am not able to get it

Comment: when i launch app from xcode than it is not crashing.